# How to convert *text* to {\i text} with sed?

Tags: sed, replace

I would like to replace every occurrence of *text* into {\i text}.

```
text *text* text
*text* text *text*
*text text text* text
```

should become

```
text {\i text} text
{\i text} text {\i text}
{\i text text text} text
```

etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that each occurrence of `*some text*` is on a single line (ie. not split across multiple lines):

```
sed -r 's/\*([^*]+)\*/{\\i \1}/g' file
```

Comment: looks nice, just one \ missed (perhaps through autoformatting): sed -r 's/\*([^*]+)\*/{\\\i \1}/g' file

Comment: I did it this way in three steps: sed -e "s/^\*/{\\\i /g" -e "s/ \*/ {\\\i /g" -e "s/\*/}/g" file

Comment: It may depend on which `sed` you use. I get the same output with `\\\i` as with `\\i`.  I am using `GNU sed version 4.2.1'

Comment: Note that the syntax is GNU specific, so would  have to be adapted when ported to a non-GNU system.

Comment: It's running on windows. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

With any POSIX `sed`, and if the `*...*` may span multiple lines, you could do:

```
sed -e :1 -e 's/\*\([^*]\{1,\}\)\*/{\\i \1}/g;/\*/!b' -e '$q;N;b1'
```

Note that some `sed` implementations have a relatively low limit on the size of their pattern space, so those may fail if the `*...*` span too many (long) lines.

With perl:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\*(.*?)\*/{\\i $1}/gs'
```

But beware that it slurps the whole file in memory prior to  doing the substitutions which could be a problem for huge files. Also note that `perl` has a `-i` option to update the file in place (which some `sed` implementations have borrowed)